# Colors look different on other screens

Tags: color-spaces, calibration

Colors look great after editing in photoshop/lightroom at my screen! But when I look on all other screens the pictures look to warm (allmost yellow!) and to much contrast… is there something wrong with my screen? Can someone help me? I remember that a year ago I used quickgamma tool to optimalize my screen colors but don’t know how to retore to stock screen colors on my Asus laptop.

Best Johnny